# Internal email goes to junk mail

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2013, outlook-web-app

We are on exchange server 2013, all users are using OWA to access their emails. One user now is facing a problem. All emails he received from a specific **internal** email address went to junk mail directly. I thought the cause was bad "Inbox rules", but even I removed all "rules", the emails from that sender still go to junk mail....

This only happens to one user, no one else has the same issue. I checked all settings on the server for his account and all settings inside OWA under his login, there is nothing else to setup for incoming rules ....

I tested with some other accounts to receive emails from that sender with and without few rules, they all working well.

Where should I start troubleshooting? Or is there a way to re-set the account settings to default?

Comment: Are you able to just disable the junk folder?  In my experience, that's always the best solution... it's just so unconfigurable and opaque that disabling it and doing almost anything else is a better approach, not that management ever understands that.

Comment: No, I cant, junk folder is global settings across company and no one can delete that folder from OWA. we need to have junk mail function enabled because it works with 3rd party filter applictions for spams

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

There is a option must be UNCHECKED

Option - Block & Allow -"Don't trust email unless it comes from someone in my Safe Senders and Recipients list or local senders"

As long as this option checked, all the emails from a specific internal sender go to junk mail directly.

UNCHECKED this option, all working well now

[image]